# How to make items wrap in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement something similar to the screenshot below (the first screenshot); i.e., items that wrap when they reach the maximum one column can fit. This example was taken from [this project](https://github.com/Microsoft/ConferenceVision) in GitHub (unfortunately, the project is too old that I was unable to run it and see the result).

Inspired by the aforementioned project, I tried the following inside a content page:

```xml
<ScrollView>
    <FlexLayout Direction="Row" AlignContent="Center">
        <BindableLayout.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
                <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
                <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
                <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
                <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
                <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
                <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </BindableLayout.ItemsSource>
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Frame WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="Beige">
                    <FlexLayout>
                        <Button
                            BorderColor="#fff"
                            BorderWidth="1"
                            BackgroundColor="#4D000000"
                            HeightRequest="90"
                            CornerRadius="45"
                            Text="{Binding}" />
                    </FlexLayout>
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </FlexLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

However, I ended up not getting the same result; i.e., the items do not wrap (see the second screenshot).

How to make the items wrap?

[image]

[image]

Comment: CollectionView will do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the trick is adding `Wrap="Wrap"` to `FlexLayout`. So, it will be something like:

```xml
<FlexLayout Direction="Row" AlignContent="Center" Wrap="Wrap">
```

Comment: Thanks @WendyZang-MSFT; Stack Overflow did not allow me to accept the answer before 2 days have passed :)